# Spring Boot (3.1.1) Kotlin Application Returns 404 Not Found in Production

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using Kotlin in spring boot (version 3.1.1) with maven build system. Application is throwing 404 when i am trying to access my resource(rest api) in production environment but its working fine on localhost with my machine.

Localhost Url : `localhost:8080/test/hi`

Production Url : `server.ip:port/runtime-name/test/hi`

Application Web server : `Wildfly`

Command for building war file : `mvn package`

What could be possible issue for such problem ?

*I have tried with java and maven/gradle build system - **Working fine on machine and production***

**It should work after deployment on wildfly/tomcat webserver with `kotlin` and either of `maven`,`gradle` or `gradle-kotlin`.**

Quick help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

**Code :**

```
package com.example.demo2

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class Demo2Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Demo2Application>(*args)
}
```

```
package com.example.demo2

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/hi")
    fun hello(): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return ResponseEntity<String>("Hi There",HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.22</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using the same server.contextPath for production and local?

Comment: No, both are different.

Comment: What is it for both of them?

Comment: local : localhost:8080/test/hi     - (where test is controller level route name and hi is function level)

production : server.ip:port/context-root/test/hi    - ( context-root is runtime context root name and test and hi as above)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is not with your code or your application, but with your production environment. There are many possible reasons why you are getting a 404 error, such as:

- The network or infrastructure of your service is not set up properly.
- You may need to use a VPN to access your service.
- The wrong port is being used.
- The application is not running in the correct mode.
- The environment variables that are required by your application are not set correctly. (I assume that you are sure that your application running correctly)

To troubleshoot this issue, I recommend checking the following:

- Make sure that the network or infrastructure of your service is set up properly.
- Try using a VPN to access your service, if it's required.
- Check the port that you are using.
- Check the mode that your application is running in.
- Check the environment variables that are required by your application.

If you have checked all of these things and you are still getting a 404 error, then please post more details about your deployment and running environment.